# How to use most recent file according to filename pattern?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder with Excel files saved with the following format:

- `2018.01 final.xlsx`
- `2018.02 final.xlsx`
- `2018.03 final xlsx.`
- etc...

I would like to perform a `VLOOKUP` to find the most recent file according to the filename pattern. Today it would be `2018.08 final xlsx`.

If the August file is not yet saved I would like to use the previous month, i.e. July (`2018.07 final.xlsx`).

The following code opens the latest file. I would like the newest file according to the pattern, without opening it.

```
  fromPath = Sheets("Open latest file").Range("B5")
  fromPath2 = Sheets("Open latest file").Range("B6")

  If Dir(fromPath) = "" Then

    Workbooks.Open (fromPath2)

  Else

    Workbooks.Open (fromPath)

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Please include your attempts so far including the research you have performed and explain what isn't working.

Comment: Please see edit @QHarr

Comment: I don't think you saved your edit

Comment: Should be there now. Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lucky for you I've already got a function I like to use that essentially does what you're looking for:

```
Function GetMostRecentExcelFile(ByVal myDirectory As String, ByVal filePattern As String) As String

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim myFolder As Object
    Set myFolder = fso.getfolder(IIf(Right(myDirectory, 1) = "\", myDirectory, myDirectory & "\"))

    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim fname As String

    Dim currentFile As Object
    For Each currentFile In myFolder.Files
        If (currentDate = CDate(0) Or currentFile.DateCreated > currentDate) And currentFile.name Like filePattern _
            And InStr(LCase$(currentFile.name), ".xlsx") > 0 And InStr(currentFile.name, "~$") = 0 Then

            currentDate = currentFile.DateCreated
            fname = currentFile.name

        End If
    Next currentFile

    GetMostRecentExcelFile = fname

End Function
```

It will loop through the specified `myDirectory` looking for any files that match the `filePattern` that you give and will return the file with the most recently created file that matches said pattern.

**Note: It does not pick the file based on filename, only based on the file's `CreationDate`!!**

---

Here's how you'd most likely use it for your problem:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim pattern As String
    pattern = "*20##.## final*"

    Dim path As String
    path = sheets("Open latest file").Range("B5").Value2

    Dim filename As String
    filename = GetMostRecentExcelFile(path, pattern)

    If Len(filename) = 0 Or Len(Dir(filename)) = 0 Then
        path = sheets("Open latest file").Range("B6").Value2
        filename = GetMostRecentExcelFile(path, pattern)
    End If

    If Len(filename) > 0 Then
        Workbooks.Open (IIf(Right(path, 1) = "\", path, path & "\") & filename)
    Else
        MsgBox "No files found matching pattern"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Very nice @Marcucciboy2. But what if in fact 2018.08.xlsx would be the latest file you want to open but based on creationdate (maybe because of an edit) 2017.01.xlsx is detected and openend? Or is Date Created unaffected by edits (I'm unsure)? Or what if 2018.07.xlsx is simply created later than 2018.08.xlsx?

Comment: @JvdV Good point - I could adjust the pattern but that same type of problem could crop up again. I'd say I'm not sure who to trust the filenames or the file properties

Comment: @JvdV The way I was using this before, the files were generated by excel so I could definitely trust the file properties even if someone adjusted the name

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your valuable help! Sorry for the dumb question but how can I define the filepattern in vba? Thanks again

Comment: @n4pster I believe the example I put should work for you based on the filenames given above, but here is where you could get examples https://analystcave.com/vba-like-operator/#VBA_Like_operator and here's the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator#pattern-options

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, one more thing. When let's say 2019.01 doesn't exists yet, You'll need to get 2018.12. You might want to consider that creating your filepattern :)

Comment: @Marcucciboy2, yeah really think it's nice to use Date Created from files. The only downside is you have to trust in fact that no one fiddles around with the files AND the file with the latest date is in fact the file closest to your current month. Otherwise I think its a cool solution. With a small sidenote you should have it more futureproof with `"20##.##"` and OP is looking for `.xlsx` going by the information provided in the question. Please take it as positive critisism :)

Comment: @JvdV I was about to say wow that's very future proof until I realized what year it actually is...

Answer (score 1):

I really like the answer @Marcucciboy2 has given you, but in case you can't trust that the last created file actually is the file you need, you could use (adapt offcourse) something like below:

```
Sub GetFile()

Dim YR As Long, MNTH As Long
Dim FPath As String, SearchFile As String

FPath = "U:\Test\"

For YR = Year(Now()) To 1 Step -1
    For MNTH = 12 To 1 Step -1
        If MNTH < 10 Then
            SearchFile = FPath & YR & ".0" & MNTH & " final.xlsx"
        Else
            SearchFile = FPath & YR & "." & MNTH & " final.xlsx"
        End If
        If Dir(SearchFile) <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open (SearchFile)
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next MNTH
Next YR

End Sub
```

A welcome extra with this option is it wouldn't have to loop through all files saving some time.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using regex to pattern match the files in a given folder. Do a little string manipulation to only retain the date part of the strings, then use sortedList to order the qualifying file names. Then select the last item from the ordered list as being your latest filename.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLastestFile()
    Const PATH As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Testing"
    Dim fso As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object, list As Object, tempString As String
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(PATH)

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If IsFound(oFile.Name) Then
            tempString = Replace$(Left$(oFile.Name, 7), ".", vbNullString)
            With list
                If Not .contains(tempString) Then
                    .Add tempString, vbNullString
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
     Debug.Print list.Getkey(list.Count - 1)
End Sub
Public Function IsFound(ByVal inputString As String) As Boolean
    Dim re As Object
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\d{4}.\d{2}\sfinal.xlsx"
        IsFound = .test(inputString) 
    End With
End Function
```

You can try the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/6yjIK0/1).

[image: Regex]

**Regex explanation:**

\d{4}.\d{2}\sfinal.xlsx

\d{4} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{4} Quantifier — Matches exactly 4 times

. matches any character (except for line terminators)

\d{2} matches a digit (equal to [0-9])
{2} Quantifier — Matches exactly 2 times

\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

final matches the characters final literally (case sensitive)
. matches any character (except for line terminators)
xlsx matches the characters xlsx literally (case sensitive)

---

**Using a Class**

Better still would be to implement a class for the regex that has a method `IsFound`. This would avoid the continual creation and destruction of the regex object. It would instead be created with the class instantiation and then just the method called as required.

If you create a class called `RegexFileMatch` then enter the following code:

```
Option Explicit
Private re As Object
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
End Sub

Public Function IsFound(ByVal inputString As String) As Boolean
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\d{4}.\d{2}\sfinal.xlsx"
        IsFound = .test(inputString)
    End With
End Function
```

Then change the calling code in the standard module to:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLastestFile()
    Const PATH As String = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Testing"
    Dim fso As Object, oFolder As Object, oFile As Object, list As Object, tempString As String
    Set list = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(PATH)
    Dim regex As New regexFileMatch
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If regex.IsFound(oFile.Name) Then
            tempString = Replace$(Left$(oFile.Name, 7), ".", vbNullString)
            With list
                If Not .contains(tempString) Then
                    .Add tempString, vbNullString
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next
     Debug.Print list.Getkey(list.Count - 1)
End Sub
```

This becomes less expensive.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FileFinder() 

Dim strFile As String, strKey As String
Dim lngMax As Long, lngNumber As Long
Dim objDict As Object

Set objDictionary = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
intMax = 0
    strFile = Dir("C:\Users\Documents\test\*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0

        intNumber = f_NumberExtractor(strFile)
        If lngMax < lngNumber Then
            lngMax = lngNumber
        End If

        If objDictionary.exists(lngNumber) = False Then
                objDictionary.Add lngNumber, strFile
         End If
        strFile = Dir
    Loop

    MsgBox objDictionary(lngMax)

End Sub

Public Function f_NumberExtractor(ByVal str As String) As Long
'Regular expression function to get rid of non-numeric signs
Dim objRegEx As Object
Dim lngResult As Long

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "\D"
objRegEx.Global = True


lngResult = objRegEx.Replace(str, vbNullString) * 1
f_NumberExtractor = lngResult

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version, credits to @QHarr..
My files are named as

IPG MEDIA BRANDS - UPDATE - **2020-10-12**.txt

IPG MEDIA BRANDS - UPDATE - **2021-10-12**.txt

So change te RegEx  .Pattern = "\d{4}-(0?[1-9]|1[012])-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*" to fit your needs

```
Function GetLastestFile(path)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(path)
        f = 0
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            If CDate(FileDate(oFile.Name)) > f Then
                last= oFile.Name
                f = CDate(fechArchivo(oFile.Name))
            End If
        Next
    GetLastestFile = last
End Function

Function FileDate(inputString)
    Dim re As New RegExp
    With re
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\d{4}\-(0?[1-9]|1[012])\-(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])*"
        fechArchivo = .Execute(inputString)(0)
    End With
End Function
```